# How to remove No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oledbconnection

I am new to Visual Studio and C#. I have been stuck at this error for long. 
I am trying to read a ID from the database and return the respective name to a label when the submit button is clicked. 
I'm getting the error in the line

```
 OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

This is my aspx.cs code-

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!isPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\xyz\abc\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite9\Uac.mdb");






        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(" SELECT DoctorName FROM DoctorInfo WHERE DoctorID=@p", con);


        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        con.Open();

        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Label4.Text = (dr["DoctorName"].ToString());

        }
        dr.Close();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();



    }
}


public bool isPostBack { get; set; }

public OleDbConnection con { get; set; }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `parameter` to the `command` as your `command` is expecting a `parameter` named `@p` before you call `ExecuteReader`

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p",1);
```